# Launching exe from an application

Tags: c++, winapi

I have to launch an exe from other application.There is code in the internet to do it.
I wanted to discuss how the Application get the path of the other exe to launch, Since path of the exe can be any.

Is Storing in the registry or config is the option??
What an application should do if the exe  already running.
Please add possible problem one may face whiling a launching an exe from other application 
I am using c++ on VS 2008.

Comment: If you wanna launch an exe, generally you should know what it is and its path. You can hard-code it in your app, pass it in as parameter of your app, or in a config file, or whatever you want..

Comment: you are asking us questions that you need to answer. We don't know your needs. You didn't tell us what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices for launching EXE files: [ShellExecuteEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Each behaves a bit different, check them out on MSDN.

As for the varying path, the registry may be a good alternative.